# Javascript asynchronous handling without Promise and async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback, es6-promise

In this question, I just want to confirm that we cannot use `callback` to strictly handle asynchronous tasks in JavaScript.
For example, we use `Promise.then` or `async/await`:

```js
myPromise().then(callback);
// or
(async () => {
  const res = await myAsyncFunction();
  callback(res);
})()
```

I saw many examples with `callback` but they used `setTimeout`:

```js
const functionWithCallback = (asyncFunction, callback) => {
  asyncFunction();

  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
  }, 1000);
};
```

The example above is NOT `asynchronous handling` to me because we don't know the time `asyncFunction()` complete. `1000ms` here is just a number.
Do we have any way to handle it with `callback` only?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "*to strictly handle asynchronous tasks*". Also what does `myAsyncFunction`/`myPromise`/`asyncFunction` do? Please show its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> The example above is NOT asynchronous handling to me

You are right that the timing of the callback invocation does not depend on whether `myAsyncFunction` completed its asynchronous task or not. However, in the most common use of the terminology, `setTimeout` *is* calling its callback function asynchronously... always.

> I just want to confirm that we cannot use callback to strictly handle asynchronous tasks in JavaScript.

You can. But there are several things to note:

- Even promises work with a callback system: the `then` method takes a callback argument, and that callback will be executed when the promise is fulfilled. Promises do not abolish callbacks, but make it easier to work with them by allowing to chain and to avoid "callback hell".
- Before promises were available in JavaScript, there surely was already the concept of asynchronous programming.

In your examples you provided a function `myAsyncFunction`. If it is important to react when its asynchronous tasks have completed, then surely that function must somehow *notify* of that completion.

Today it is very common for such an asynchronous function to return a promise, and then the caller will of course make use of that promise (with either `then` or `await`): that's the purpose of having the promise object. A known example of such an asynchronous function is `fetch`.

If `myAsyncFunction` does not return a promise, then we would expect such a function to notify in a different way. For instance, it could take a callback as argument. Then to code looks like this:

```
myAsyncFunction(callback);
```

Known examples of such asynchronous functions are `setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame`, and `queueMicrotask`

Still other asynchronous functions are more complex, as they may provide some synchronous results and other asynchronous results. They return an object to which a listener can be attached. The code will then look something like this:

```
let res = myAsyncFunction();
res.addEventListener("ready", callback);
```

There are many examples of this in the DOM API: for instance, `document.createElement` and the `load` event (typically used with `img` and `script` elements).

A slight variation of this, is where a constructor is called with `new`, or where the object is provided first, but the asynchronous action still has to be initiated by some event, or by a method call.

There are of course many variations to this, like:

```
let res = new MyConstructor();
res.myAsyncFunction();
res.onready = callback;
```

An example of such a constructor is `XMLHttpRequest` (with its `send()` method)

### Conclusion

It really depends on how `myAsyncFunction` will notify that it has completed its asynchronous tasks. When `myAsyncFunction` returns a promise, then of course you should be using that promise. When not, there should be some way to provide your callback to the API that is offered.

Comment: Sorry I forgot `await` in the second example, just an accident.

Comment: I see. I have removed that part from my answer.

Comment: Thanks!
About something like `res.addEventListener("ready", callback)`, I thought about them. And I think that the `async` action is controlled by outside (not javascript engine). Right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `async` is a keyword that makes the function return a promise object, and allows for `await`.